# UPDATE statement in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-01036

We are building a client program where parameters for storage in a web server with Oracle backend are set in the .Net client program and uploaded as a dataset via webservice.

In the webservice code, data is read from the dataset and added to UPDATE statements on the web server (Oracle backend).

Because the server will run on the customer's LAN behind a firewall and because of the dynamic nature of the parameters involved, no sprocs are being used - SQL strings are built in the logic.

Here is an example string:

```
UPDATE WorkOrders 
   SET TravelTimeHours = :TravelTimeHours, 
       TravelTimeMinutes = :TravelTimeMinutes,  
       WorkTimeHours = :WorkTimeHours, 
       WorkTimeMinutes = :WorkTimeMinutes, 
       CompletedPersonID = :CompletedPersonID, 
       CompletedPersonName = :CompletedPersonName, 
       CompleteDate = :CompleteDate 
 WHERE WorkOrderNumber = :WorkOrderNumber
```

When debugging code in VS 2010 and stepping into the server code, we receive the following error:

```
ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number
```

when executing the SQL command on destination oracle machine, we were prompted to enter the bind 
variables for the above statement, and as long as we used the correct date format, the UPDATE statement
worked correctly.

**QUESTIONS:**

**1) is it possible that oracle threw the ORA-01036 error when the month format was wrong?**

**2) why don't we have to convert the date format from the ASP.net website running on the Oracle machine?
   does Oracle have a default conversion routine that excludes the bind variable entry screen?**

**3) if the date format was not the problem, what precisely does ORA-1036 mean and how do I discover 
   WHICH variable had an illegal name/number?**

---

This is a snippet of a function that takes the type of the dataset (WOName) and returns the appropriate SQL string.
Many Cases exist but have been removed for readability.

```
Private Function GetMainSQLString(ByVal WOName As String) As String
    Dim Result As String = ""
    Select Case WOName
        Case "Monthly Site Inspection"              
            Dim sb As New StringBuilder
            sb.Append("UPDATE WorkOrders SET ")
            sb.Append("CompletedPersonID = :CompletedPersonID, CompletedPersonName = :CompletedPersonName, CompleteDate = :CompleteDate, ")
            sb.Append("SupervisorID = :SupervisorID, SupervisorName = :SupervisorName ")
            sb.Append("WHERE WorkOrderNumber = :WorkOrderNumber")
            Result = sb.ToString
    End Select
    Return Result
End Function
```

This is a snippet of a function that takes the Oracle command object byRef and adds the required parameters to it, 
depending upon which of the possible 15 types of dataset(WOName) is received from the client program.
Many Cases exist but have been removed for readability.

The updated Cmd object is then returned to the main program logic, where ExecuteNonQuery() is called.

The test values of params below are as follows:

```
dr.Item("CompletedPersonID")    21
dr.Item("CompletedPersonName")  Pers Name
dr.Item("CompleteDate")     #8/16/2010#
dr.Item("SupervisorID")     24
dr.Item("SupervisorName")   Sup Name
dr.Item("WorkOrderNumber")  100816101830


Private Function addMainCmdParams(ByVal WOName As String, ByRef cmd As OracleCommand, ByVal dr As DataRow) As OracleCommand
    Select Case WOName
        Case "Monthly Site Inspection"              
            cmd.Parameters.Add(":CompletedPersonID", Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDbType.Int32).Value = dr.Item("CompletedPersonID")
            cmd.Parameters.Add(":CompletedPersonName", Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = dr.Item("CompletedPersonName")
            cmd.Parameters.Add(":CompleteDate", Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDbType.Date).Value = dr.Item("CompleteDate")
            cmd.Parameters.Add(":SupervisorID", Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDbType.Int32).Value = dr.Item("SupervisorID")
            cmd.Parameters.Add(":SupervisorName", Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = dr.Item("SupervisorName")
            cmd.Parameters.Add(":WorkOrderNumber", Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = dr.Item("WorkOrderNumber")
    End Select
    Return cmd
End Function
```

While running this today, this precise code WAS successful; but another similar case was not. I still distrust any implicit typecasting performed by Oracle (if any) - and I'm especially suspicious of how Oracle handles any of these parameters that are passed with a dbNull.value - and I know it's going to happen. so if that's the problem I'll have to work around it. There are too many optional parameters and columns that don't always get values passed in for this system to break on nulls.

Answer (score 3):

One Oracle "gotcha" that can cause this error is the fact that, by default, Oracle maps parameters to parameter symbols in the query by sequence, not by name. If the number/type of parameters does not match, you get an error like this one.

The solution is to tell Oracle to bind by name:

```
cmd.BindByName = true
```

Without diving into the details of your code, this may or may not be the answer to your specific problem, but this setting should be the default, and should be part of any command setup that uses parameters. It's rather amazing to watch this one statement fix some obscure problems.

EDIT: This assumes that you're using Oracle's data access provider. In .NET, you should be using this, not Microsoft's Oracle provider.

Answer (score 1):

The error has nothing to do with date formats, it means that a variable in the statement was not bound.

Could be as simple as a spelling mistake (would be nice if Oracle included the variable name in the error message).

Can you update your question with the surrounding code that creates, binds, and executes the statement?

Comment: Thanks for your answer Thilo, I'll update at work tomorrow.

SF

Answer (score -1):

This is a snippet of a function that takes the type of the dataset (WOName) and returns the appropriate SQL string.
Many Cases exist but have been removed for readability.

```
Private Function GetMainSQLString(ByVal WOName As String) As String
    Dim Result As String = ""
    Select Case WOName
        Case "Monthly Site Inspection"              
            Dim sb As New StringBuilder
            sb.Append("UPDATE WorkOrders SET ")
            sb.Append("CompletedPersonID = :CompletedPersonID, CompletedPersonName = :CompletedPersonName, CompleteDate = :CompleteDate, ")
            sb.Append("SupervisorID = :SupervisorID, SupervisorName = :SupervisorName ")
            sb.Append("WHERE WorkOrderNumber = :WorkOrderNumber")
            Result = sb.ToString
    End Select
    Return Result
End Function
```

This is a snippet of a function that takes the Oracle command object byRef and adds the required parameters to it, 
depending upon which of the possible 15 types of dataset(WOName) is received from the client program.
Many Cases exist but have been removed for readability.

The updated Cmd object is then returned to the main program logic, where ExecuteNonQuery() is called.

The test values of params below are as follows:

```
dr.Item("CompletedPersonID")    21
dr.Item("CompletedPersonName")  Pers Name
dr.Item("CompleteDate")     #8/16/2010#
dr.Item("SupervisorID")     24
dr.Item("SupervisorName")   Sup Name
dr.Item("WorkOrderNumber")  100816101830


Private Function addMainCmdParams(ByVal WOName As String, ByRef cmd As OracleCommand, ByVal dr As DataRow) As OracleCommand
    Select Case WOName
        Case "Monthly Site Inspection"              
            cmd.Parameters.Add(":CompletedPersonID", Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDbType.Int32).Value = dr.Item("CompletedPersonID")
            cmd.Parameters.Add(":CompletedPersonName", Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = dr.Item("CompletedPersonName")
            cmd.Parameters.Add(":CompleteDate", Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDbType.Date).Value = dr.Item("CompleteDate")
            cmd.Parameters.Add(":SupervisorID", Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDbType.Int32).Value = dr.Item("SupervisorID")
            cmd.Parameters.Add(":SupervisorName", Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = dr.Item("SupervisorName")
            cmd.Parameters.Add(":WorkOrderNumber", Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = dr.Item("WorkOrderNumber")
    End Select
    Return cmd
End Function
```

While running this today, this precise code WAS successful; but another similar case was not. I still distrust any implicit typecasting performed by Oracle (if any) - and I'm especially suspicious of how Oracle handles any of these parameters that are passed with a dbNull.value - and I know it's going to happen. so if that's the problem I'll have to work around it. There are too many optional parameters and columns that don't always get values passed in for this system to break on nulls.

Comment: You should have edited your question to include this information (which I have done for you).  Answers are supposed to be, well, *answers*.